# How to get all the objects whose tags are subset of tags in list Django-taggit

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-taggit

I am using django-taggit for tagging.

```
class Taggedwebsites(TaggedItemBase):
  content_object = models.ForeignKey('website')

class website(models.Model):
      tags=TaggableManager(through=Taggedwebsites,blank=True)
```

Now I want all the website whose tags are superset of tags list provided dynamically.

For example,

```
tag_list=['python','django','database']
```

Then I want all the website objects which must have at least these three sets.

```
result=website.objects.filter(tags__name_on=tag_list).distinct()
```

doesn't works as it doesn't gives object whose tags are superset of tag_list.

How to perform this query in filter?

Answer (score -1):

In the query "tags__name_on" the 'on' word is not define in django, you should use in instead. You want the objects with objects which must have at least these three sets, you should use the 'in' parameter. Here is the documentation for the querysets : docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#in

try:

```
result=website.objects.filter(tags__name__in=tag_list).distinct()
```

or:

```
result=website.objects.distinct(tags__name__in=tag_list)
```

Comment: Please explain these solutions (and their differences) in English. Thanks.

Comment: ok, he has the a not define query "tags__name_on" the 'on' word is not define in django, you should use in instead. 
he wants the objects with objects which must have at least these three sets, he should use the 'in' parameter.
here is the documentation for the querysets :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I was trying to say that you should improve you answer to explain how the solution works. That makes your answer more understandable, and can make it useful to more people than just the original poster. Thanks.

Comment: I get  DatabaseError “more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression”

Comment: @Forethinker that's probably because you use .get in the query.